# Flutter : Save and Fetch ImageNetwork from API using SQFlite

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem with Insert and Fetch Image From API to local Directory.

So i have code to save image like this :

#### Save Image Code

```
Future saveImage(String imgUrl, String imgUrl2) async {
    var response = await http.get("$baseURLimage/berita/$imgUrl");
    var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File file = File(join(documentDirectory.path, imgUrl2));
    file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
    print(response);
    print(response.bodyBytes);
    print(documentDirectory);
    print(file);
return file;
  }
```

#### Button Code

```
 void _saveImage() async {
    var saveImage =
        await api.saveImage(widget.gambarBerita, widget.gambarBerita);
    print(saveImage);
  }
```

In Console give me this :

```
I/flutter (23336): Instance of 'Response'
I/flutter (23336): [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 132, 0, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 13, 14, 16, 16, 14, 20, 22, 19, 22, 20, 30, 27, 25, 25, 27, 30, 45, 32, 34, 32, 34, 32, 45, 68, 42, 50, 42, 42, 50, 42, 68, 60, 73, 59, 55, 59, 73, 60, 108, 85, 75, 75, 85, 108, 125, 105, 99, 105, 125, 151, 135, 135, 151, 190, 181, 190, 249, 249, 255, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 13, 14, 16, 16, 14, 20, 22, 19, 22, 20, 30, 27, 25, 25, 27, 30, 45, 32, 34, 32, 34, 32, 45, 68, 42, 50, 42, 42, 50, 42, 68, 60, 73, 59, 55, 59, 73, 60, 108, 85, 75, 75, 85, 108, 125, 105, 99, 105, 125, 151, 135, 135, 151, 190, 181, 190, 249, 249, 255, 255, 192, 0, 17, 8, 11, 244, 8, 88, 3, 1, 34, 0, 2, 17, 1, 3, 17, 1, 255, 196, 0, 156, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 16, 0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 0, 0, 1, 13, 0, 1, 2, 3, 17, 4, 18, 33, 49, 5, 19, 65, 81, 34, 50, 97, 20, 113, 6, 35, 66, 82, 21, 51, 129, 145, 161, 36, 52, 98, 114, 177, 67, 83, 37, 53, 115, 22, 68, 99, 193, 8
I/flutter (23336): Directory: '/data/user/0/com.example.flutter_news/app_flutter'
I/flutter (23336): File: '/data/user/0/com.example.flutter_news/app_flutter/92dae9b51087d930a32aff53eaded163.jpg'
I/flutter (23336): File: '/data/user/0/com.example.flutter_news/app_flutter/92dae9b51087d930a32aff53eaded163.jpg'
```

But my images still not saved in my device.

can you help me ?

Comment: You aren't returning any value from `saveImage`. Try returning `file`. Since you don't return anything now, it returns null.

Comment: I already returning `file`, but Image not saved into my device.
something wrong ? console not give me error

Comment: We can't know what is that `api.saveImage` doing. Check that. You can try printing the file contents to be sure. Replace `print(saveImage)` with `print(await (new File(saveImage).readAsString()));`

Comment: hmmm, after i edit give me error `_TypeError (type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String')`

Comment: Looks like `saveImage` is already of type `File`. So you can do `print(await saveImage.readAsString());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/network_to_file_image 
In demo, it download image and show it, so you can see success or not directly
From official introduction  
This is a mixture of FileImage and NetworkImage. It will download the image from the url once, save it locally in the file system, and then use it from there in the future.

full example code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:network_to_file_image/network_to_file_image.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

String flutterLogoUrl =
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Google-flutter-logo.png";

String flutterLogoFileName = "flutter.png";

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Demo(
        url: flutterLogoUrl,
        file: await file(flutterLogoFileName),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Future<File> file(String filename) async {
  Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String pathName = p.join(dir.path, filename);
  return File(pathName);
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final File file;

  const Demo({Key key, this.url, this.file}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Network to file image example')),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Image(image: NetworkToFileImage(url: url, file: file, debug: true)),
        ),
      );
}
```

In demo picture, you can see it print image url and saved file path

[image]

Comment: Thank's for your response, but i have some problem . I'm totally follow documentation but with different ways, I have code like this : https://gist.github.com/zgramming/3b3428e69cf6125d8237605f070ef5cc. But i get error `The await expression can only be used in an async function.Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'`. I know i must include `async` , but i dont know where to place this. Can you help me ?

Comment: please remove await and temp path is a fixed value. please get temp path without Future. if you do this in ListView.buider it will try to git temp directory every time it build and will slowdown your app.